# Excel Match with reverse wildcards

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

this is my table:

```
   A                 B                   c
1  foo.com/page1     foo.com/page1?xyz
2  foo.com/page2     foo.com/page1?abc
3  foo.com/page3     foo.com/page8?xyz
```

for each item in columnB, I want to know if is there a matching item on ColumnA
(the result should be: B1>TRUE,B2>TRUE,B3>FALSE)

I've tried this:

```
 =match(B1, A:A&"*")
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

This solution narrowly applies to your example.

Using VLOOKUP approximate match instead of exact match, you have the ability to do something of a "fuzzy" match like you're describing.

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(B1,LEN(VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,TRUE)))=VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,TRUE),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Basically the formula is looking for the closest match it can find using your single long string and searching your many shorter strings.

- It identifies the first close match
- Verifies all characters in your A column match are represented in
  your column B string beginning with the left-most character
- Returns TRUE if all characters in the A match are represented in your
  B string
- Returns FALSE if not all characters in the A match are represented in
  your B string

**Weakness (why this may fail with true data):**

The example contains page numbers 1, 2, 3. If column B string is page 11, this formula will return TRUE when it matches 1 (it will not go looking for 11).